# How to annotate functions to aid code analysis

Tags: c++, sal

Consider the following functions:

```
constexpr bool IsNull(const int* arg)
{
    return arg == nullptr;
}

void Test()
{
    int x{ 42 };
    int* p = &x;    // C26429 : Symbol 'p' is never tested for nullness
    if (!IsNull(p))
        *p = 5;
}
```

Warning C26429 occurs because the compiler does not 'see' the pointer check inside of function `IsNull()`.

MSVC has the `__assume(exp)` intrinsic function to tell the compiler that `exp` should be considered `true`. But is there any way to annotate function `IsNull` to indicate that a certain *post condition* has been met if it returns `true`? Similar to the SAL annotations?

I haven't found anything so I think I have to revert to converting `IsNull` into a macro function:

```
#define IsNull(P) (!(P))
```

Comment: The function assert raises a run-time error in debug mode if its argument is false.

Comment: Why don't you just write `p != nullptr` (or `p`, as old farts like me would)?

Comment: are you looking for something msvc specific? I couldnt reproduce the warning https://godbolt.org/z/Yb1cEPx9x. And I dont understand the warning. It is not possible that `p` is `nullptr` even without considering `isNull`

Comment: What is your version of MSVC?

Comment: Would this help? `if (!IsNull(p)) *gsl::not_null<int*>{p} = 5;`